# Keeping association between values from a previously unsorted list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

So, I have this text file with the signs of chemical elements and their corresponding weights, like:

`Ac 227.0Ag 107.868Al 26.98154Am 241.1`... and so on

What I want to do is sort it according to weight instead of alphabetical order.
My  first attempt was to create a list with only the weights and then use a mergesort  algorithm to sort it  numerically. For this i used the code:

```
atomdata=open('atomdata.txt').read()
alist=atomdata.split()
weightlist=[]
for part in alist:
    if alist.index(part)%2!=0:
        weight=part
        weightlist.append(float(weight))
sortweight=mergesort(weightlist)
```

But now that the weights are sorted, I cannot figure out how to sort/map the signs to their corresponding weights correctly. I've thought about using a dictionary, but I still  don't  know how  to sort them so that the signs get the correct order.

Comment: why is `Ac` on its own?

Comment: Did you write your own sorting code? Don't do that. Use the built-in library `sort` (or `sorted`, if you want a separate, new list).

Comment: On what you have provided I have no idea how  `if alist.index(part)%2!=0:`  separates your data

Comment: It takes out the weights and puts them in a separate list (without the signs of the chemical elements).

Comment: How could it do that if a line is `Ac 227.0Ag 107.868Al 26.98154Am 241.1`? DO you actually have spaces between them in your file?

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda weird but there are spaces...

Comment: @nekomeido, ok try the answer I provided

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function

```
>>> elements = "22Ac 227.0Ag 107.868Al 26.98154Am 241.1Ar"
>>> sorted(elements.split(), key=lambda x: float(x[:-2]))
['22Ac', '26.98154Am', '107.868Al', '227.0Ag', '241.1Ar']
```

You can read more on sorting [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't just `split()` the input, since the spaces are not separating each pair, but rather separating the name with the value.  i.e. `Ac` corresponds to `227.0` and `Ag` corresponds to `107.86`.

One solution is:

```
import re
weights = re.findall('[^ ]+ \d+\.\d+', input)
weights.sort(key=lambda x: float(x.split(" ")[1]))
```

With input

```
Ac 227.0Ag 107.868Al 26.98154Am 241.1Ar
```

this results in

```
['Al 26.98154', 'Ag 107.868', 'Ac 227.0', 'Am 241.1']
```

You can easilly reformat this list to whatever you need.

Comment: Regular expressions are a very nice idea in this case, but could you explain your *pattern in string*?

Comment: @elegent, what do you mean by explain the pattern in string?

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean the pattern you passed to the `findall()` function (`'[^ ]+ \d+\.\d+'`). :)

Comment: sure!  The thing I dislike about regex is how unreadable regular expressions are.  So I am searching for any non-space character one or more times, followed by a space, followed by a floating point number.   The non-space character forces each match to contain exactly one space, and thus each match must be one name, value pair, e.g. `Al 26.98`.

Comment: Thanks :) You are right they are unreadable but also very powerful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you data is actually separated by whitespace you can create a dict and sort the items:

```
with open('atomdata.txt') as f:
   it = iter(f.read().split())    
   d =  dict(zip(it,it))    
   print(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: float(x[1])))
```

Using your example line:

```
s ="Ac 227.0 Ag 107.868 Al 26.98154 Am 241.1"

it = iter(s.split())

d =  dict(zip(it,it))  

print(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: float(x[1])))
[('Al', '26.98154'), ('Ag', '107.868'), ('Ac', '227.0'), ('Am', '241.1')]
```

You can do it without reading all the content into memory also using itertools.chain:

```
from itertools import chain
with open('atomdata.txt') as f:
   it = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f)
   d =  dict(zip(it,it))
   print(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: float(x[1])))
```

If you really want a the items back in a list you can chain the result:

```
print(list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: float(x[1])))))
```